# Process Builder: How can I call another object while creating Work Order?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, field-service-lightning, asset, work-order

I'm trying to make the following happen. When creating a Work Order there are two fields that hold a master-relationship (Accounts & Assets). I want to create a process that allows me to call the account that the asset belongs too as soon as I fill it up. Example...

When I pick X **Asset** , I want the **Account** that the **Asset** belongs too to be automatically filled.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can get there from here.
If you rely on Process Builder to do this... it will set values AFTER your DB commit attempt. So during create or edit on "Work Order", your users will select only "Asset" via lookup. Users won't need to set "Account" on "Work Order". Then, on DB commit attempt, the Process Builder can definitely set that "Work Order's" "Account" based on association with the selected "Asset".

This help article outlines a solution for a similar situation, have a look.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220643&language=en_US&type=1

Finally, if you want a nice user experience (GUI stuff), i.e. you want the 
Account field to dynamically populate DURING CREATE/EDIT mode based on lookup selection of Asset... then you are going to have to explore other solutions... such as Visual Flow, or custom lightning component.

Comment: you will need to relax required field settings on the "Account" field as well.

Comment: N.B. depending on the application, Asset.AccountId may already be prepopulated as AccountId is required on Asset if ContactId is null. This could simplify the solution